# How do I load a VSTO gallery control dynamically

Tags: vsto

I'm looking for a sample code or document which describe How VSTO gallery control is dynamically load

tx

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where I load the images in the gallery dynamically.

**Ribbon.xml**

```
<gallery id="galleryConvertTable" columns="1" onAction="galleryConvertTable_Click"
         getItemCount="galleryConvertTable_getItemCount"
         imageMso="CreateTable" size="large" label="Convert to Table"
         getEnabled="galleryConvertTable_getEnabled"
         getItemImage="tableforNumbers_getImage">                     
</gallery>
```

**Ribbon.cs**

```
public int galleryConvertTable_getItemCount(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
   return GetTableStylesCount();
}

public void galleryConvertTable_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control, string selectedId, int selectedIndex)
{
    ConvertToTable(selectedIndex);
}

public Bitmap tableforNumbers_getImage(Office.IRibbonControl control, int itemIndex)
{
    switch (itemIndex)
    {
       case 0:
           return Resources.TableforNumbers;
       case 1:
           return Resources.TableforNumbersWithLines;
       case 2:
           return Resources.TableforText;
       case 3:
           return Resources.TableforTextwithLines;
     }
     return Resources.TableforNumbers;
}
```

if you change `getItemImage` to `getItemLabel` and the method signature is

```
public string getItemLabel(IRibbonControl control, int index)
```

More in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736142%28v=office.12%29.aspx)